# Strings: Primitive type variables or reference type variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

I was reading in my javascript book again today and it was explaining the difference between reference type variables and primitive type variables. It gave these examples to illustrate the difference.

**Example 1 (Primitive Type)**

```
var a = 3.14;
var b = a;
a = 4;
alert( b ); // Displays 3.14
```

**Example 2 (Reference Type)**

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = a;
var a[0] = 99;
alert( b ); // Displays the changed array [99, 2, 3]
```

I understand this example and I don't have any questions about it. My question is about strings in javascript. Intuitively, I would assume that strings are reference type variables because if the dynamic size, but I was messing around with them on example.com and I created this example which seems to indicate that strings are primitive type variables.

**Example 3 (Strings?)**

```
var a = 'Ben';
var b = a;
var a = 'Benjamin';
alert( b ); //Displays the unchanged 'Ben'
```

I've searched around here on stack overflow and on google and I found a few articles that talked about this but most of them were talking about other languages such as Java and C#.

**Question:**
*In javascript are Strings considered primitive or reference variable types and are there any other situations that I should be aware of where Strings work differently then I would expect?*

Comment: If you try example 3 with the array `['B','e','n']`, you would get the same results - when you assign a new value (another array) to the `a` variable which does not affect `b`. Try example 2 (where you alter the `0` field of `a`) with a string - it would throw an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In JavaScript, strings are *immutable*, and therefore a primitive type.

That they have variable sizes is just like numbers of different magnitude. Their size is not *dynamic*, you cannot change the size of an existing string value. Whenever you do string operations, you are creating new values. Just like `var x = 1; x += 2` won't change the `1` value (but create a new `3` value), `var var a = "Hi!"; a += "!"` won't change the string `"Hi!"`.

Comment: `var a = "Hi!"; a += "!";` You can add characters to a string so their size can change, but you can't do, say `a[2] = "?"`.

Comment: Though this is likely subject to the implementation choice in the JS engine, strings are likely passed by reference (e.g. no copy is made when passed around to other users of the same string), but because they are immutable and a given string can never be changed, they end up behaving more like primitives.

Comment: @NobleMushtak - that's not really right.  When you "change" a string, it makes a new string.  The original string was never changed.  Try this:  `var a = "Hi!"; var b = a;  a += "!";`.  Now look at `b` and `a`.  They are different, showing you that the string in a wasn't really changed, but a new string was created with the change in it.

Comment: @NobleMushtak: No, you are not adding a character. You are creating a new string by the concatenation of `Hi!` and `!`, which you then assign to the `a` variable. And yes, you cannot assign to `a[2]`.

Comment: Hm...OK. Thanks for the clarification. Sorry for down-voting your answer. @jfriend00

Comment: Thanks @Bergi! That answer is short and fixes my understanding of Strings.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `a = 'Benjamin'`, the assignment operator (`=`) changes the object to which `a` points. It does not change to what object other variables point. To illustrate:

```
var a, b;

a = "Ben";      // `a` now points to "Ben" in memory
b = a;          // `b` now points to "Ben" in memory
a = "Benjamin"; // `a` now points to "Benjamin" in memory, but
                // `b` still points to "Ben"
```

This isn't anything special to do with strings; the semantics are the same for any primitive or object value.

An important part of the answer to your question is, as Bergi points out, that strings in JavaScript are immutable, and so regardless of implementation they act, essentially, as primitives. Again, to illustrate:

```
a = "Ben";    // `a` now points to "Ben" in memory
b = a;        // `b` now points to "Ben" in memory
a += "jamin"; // `a` now points to "Benjamin" in memory, but
              // `b` still points to "Ben"
```

`a += "jamin"`, which as you know is equivalent to `a = a + "jamin"`, doesn't change the string that `a` and `b` point to; it creates a new string with the value `"Benjamin"` and makes `a` point to it instead of `"Ben"`. (Whether or not `"Ben"` and `"Benjamin"` share any of the same bytes in memory is an implementation detail that is completely opaque to the JavaScript program.)

Comment: The question would rather be whether `"Ben"` (in `a`) and `"Ben"` (in `b`) do share bytes in memory… The point is that they do not from JavaScript's point of view, and that it does not even know of something like a "byte sequence object" in "memory".

Comment: @Bergi I think you and I just said the same thing.

Comment: Ah, right, I just referred to the state after the `b = a;` assignment. Didn't really understand what the `"jamin"` adds to the explanation…

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript strings are primitives.

There is a thing you should be avare of, though. Wraper objects. primitives like strings, numbers, booleans get wrapped up in objects, so you can call properties on these wrapper objects, for insance:

```
var foo = 'bar';
var poo = foo.slice(0,-1)
poo == 'ar'; //true
```

Here string 'bar' is wrapped up in object that has slice method ( and many others ), but in all other cases ( when you just pass primitive variables around, etc. ) the variable is just a primitive.

Comment: The wrapper object is only "created" for looking up the property (which the engine will optimize away), you cannot observe it (unless in sloppy mode)

Comment: what do you mean, 'observe' it?

Comment: You cannot log it, show it, use it… All it does is it gives a property, you never see the actual wrapper object (in your example). There's no reason to be aware of anything.

Answer (score 0):

Example 3 doesn't work because, as Jordan said, if you change the value of an actual object and not just a property, the objects that object point to won't change even though object is a reference type in JavaScript.

However, strings are immutable and primitive values, so even if we did something like this:

```
var a = "Hi!";
var b = a;
a[2] = "?";
alert(a);
alert(b);
```

`a` would still be `"Hi!"` because strings are immutable and `b` would still be `"Hi!"` even if `a` was `"Hi?"` because strings are primitive values.